# MySQL Stored Procedure pass in very large string values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string

Is there a way to pass extremely long string values to a Stored Procedure? I know that there is a limit on VARCHAR of upwards to 64,000, but it is possible that the string that I am passing may be more than that. In my case, I am passing a query string. Yes, an extremely long query string, that will update almost the entire table in 1 go. I am doing it all at once because efficiency is extremely important app side, and so I just generate the sql, and pass it to a stored procedure. The reason this query string could be so long, is that I am updating about 12 columns for possibly 100 rows, and I do that with very large CASE statements.

Anyway, Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Q) How many bytes are some of these queries?  Q) Exactly what error did you get when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html

Stored procedure (and function) arguments (and the returned value for stored functions) can be defined with one of the `*TEXT` data types.

```
TINYTEXT   up to 2^8-1 bytes
TEXT       up to 2^16-1 bytes
MEDIUMTEXT up to 2^24-1 bytes
LONGTEXT   up to 2^32-1 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an auxiliary table with logic from CASE statements and rewriting your query to use that data to modify target table?

For instance, assuming we are using values from col1 and col2 columns to update col3 like in:

```
CREATE TABLE Target (
  col1 CHAR(1),
  col2 CHAR(1),
  col3 CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Target VALUES('a', 'b', 'x');
INSERT INTO Target VALUES('c', 'b', 'x');
INSERT INTO Target VALUES('c', 'd', 'y');
INSERT INTO Target VALUES('e', 'f', 'z');

UPDATE Target
SET col3 = CASE
  WHEN col1 = 'a' THEN 'i'
  WHEN col1 = 'c' AND col2 = 'b' THEN 'i'
  WHEN col1 = 'c' AND col2 = 'd' THEN 'j'
  WHEN col2 = 'f' THEN 'k'
  END;
```

You can create Aux auxiliary table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Aux (
  col1 CHAR(1),
  col2 CHAR(1),
  col3 CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Aux VALUES ('a', NULL, 'i');
INSERT INTO Aux VALUES ('c', 'b', 'i');
INSERT INTO Aux VALUES ('c', 'd', 'j');
INSERT INTO Aux VALUES (NULL, 'f', 'k');
```

And rewrite update query to something like that:

```
UPDATE
  Target t,
  Aux a
SET
  t.col3 = a.col3
WHERE
  COALESCE(t.col1, a.col1, '0') = COALESCE(a.col1, t.col1, '0')
AND
  COALESCE(t.col2, a.col1, '0') = COALESCE(a.col2, t.col2, '0');
```

I hope this simple example can serve as an inspiration.